# how to draw a dynamic json based chart using amcharts api in asp.net?

Tags: json, database, dynamic, amcharts

I'm Kaushik.

I want to generate a column type chart using the amcharts chart api on an asp.net webpage, say, "display.aspx". The requirement is that the chart takes data in the form of "json" data and draw a graph. My requirement is to retrieve the data from sql server and then produce that data into json and thus populate the chart with the generated json data. I did the same. But, i'm not successful as there is no chart that is being shown on the webpage when I ran the website in visual studio.
Here, are the two code files that I have : JSONData.aspx and JSONData.aspx.cs

This is the JSONData.aspx page that I have.

```html
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="JSONData.aspx.cs" Inherits="New_DataQuest.JSONData" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script src="jquery-2.1.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="amcharts/amcharts.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="amcharts/serial.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <%--<script type="text/javascript">
        $('Button1').click(function () {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/JSONData.aspx.cs/GetJsonData",
                data: "[]",
                contentType: "application/json;chartset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                async: true,
                cache: false,
            });
            return false;
        });
    </script>--%>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        // code to draw the chart in javascript as given in the website "http://www.amcharts.com/tutorials/your-first-chart-with-amcharts/"
        $(AmCharts).ready(function () {
            var chart = new AmCharts.AmSerialChart();
            var j = '<%=GetJsonData()%>';//this statement should get the json data from code behind page to the variable "j"
            chart.dataProvider = j;//the json data in the var j is given to the data provider.
            chart.categoryField = "subject";

            var graph = new AmCharts.AmGraph();
            graph.valueField = "marks";
            graph.type = "column";
            chart.addGraph(graph);
            //var categoryAxis = chart.categoryAxis;
            //categoryAxis.autoGridCount = false;
            //categoryAxis.gridCount = chart.dataProvider.length;
            //categoryAxis.gridPosition = "start";
            //categoryAxis.labelRotation = 90;
            //graph.fillAlphas = 0.2;
            chart.write('chartdiv');
        });
    </script>
    <%--This code is to check whether the json data from the code behind file is getting generated or not. --%>
    <%--<script>
        var js = '<%=jsondata%>';
        $(document).ready(function () {
            alert(js);
        });
    </script>--%>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Show JSON data" OnClick="Button1_Click" />
        <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" OnClick="Button2_Click" Text="Draw Chart" />
        <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" EnablePageMethods="true"></asp:ScriptManager>
        <div id="chartdiv" style="width:1300px;height:500px"></div>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

2. Here, is the second page, the code behind file JSONData.aspx.cs

```html
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data.Sql;
using System.Text;
using System.Web.Services;

namespace New_DataQuest
{
    public partial class JSONData : System.Web.UI.Page
    {

        public string jsondata = GetJsonData();
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           
        }
        [WebMethod]//webmethod for a static getjsondata function so that the method can be accessed using jquery in aspx page.
        public static string GetJsonData()
        {
            //sql connection
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
            con.ConnectionString = "Initial Catalog=asti;Data Source=KAUSHIK;user ID=sa;password=kaushik1993";
            string query = "select [Subject Name], [Total] from [asti_data] where [Year]='1' and [Student ID]='11M91A0527'";
            con.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);
            SqlDataReader dr;
            dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            //create a JSON string to describe the data from the database
           
            StringBuilder JSON = new StringBuilder();
            string prefix = "";
            JSON.Append("[");
            while(dr.Read())
            {
                JSON.Append(prefix+"{");
                JSON.Append("\"subject\":"+"\""+dr[0]+"\",");
                JSON.Append("\"marks\":" + dr[1]);
                JSON.Append("}");
                prefix = ",";
            }
            JSON.Append("]");
            
            return JSON.ToString();
        }

        protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //Response.Write(jsondata);
            
        }

        protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            
        }
        
    }
}
```

Here, is the sample database picture that i would like to attach.
Visit this link to get the picture. "https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-JER42be41TSGJmVVV3bXJEcEk/view?usp=sharing"

The main aim is to generate the data from the database and convert it into JSON data and populate the chart's "dataProvider" property/method with this JSON data in order to draw a chart.
Basically, the x-axis would contain the subjects and the y-axis would contain the marks secured by the student.

Now, I would like to know what is actually going wrong in the coding part. I would be really thankful to those who would share their valuable time in answering this question. 
Thank you so much.

Comment: So is this a data request problem or an amCharts problem? I'm not able to debug it, so could you pls post the resulting JSON?

Comment: yup.. this is the resulting JSON.. @gerric

Comment: [{"subject":"ENGLISH ","marks":82},{"subject":"MATHEMATICS - I ","marks":59},{"subject":"ENGINEERING PHYSICS ","marks":70},{"subject":"ENGINEERING CHEMISTRY ","marks":76},{"subject":"COMPUTER PROGRAMMING & DATA STRUCTURES ","marks":82},{"subject":"MATHEMATICAL METHODS ","marks":71},{"subject":"ENGINEERING DRAWING ","marks":68},{"subject":"COMPUTER PROGRAMMING LAB ","marks":75},{"subject":"ENGG. PHYSICS & ENGG. CHEMISTRY LAB ","marks":73},{"subject":"ENGLISH LANGUAGE COMMUNICATION SKILLS LAB ","marks":72},{"subject":"IT WORKSHOP & ENGINEERING WORKSHOP ","marks":69}]

Comment: Copy the json and paste it in "www.jsonlint.com/" for validating the JSON data..

Comment: So i got your data [running](http://jsfiddle.net/ayy5fbj5/). Try to debug your page and look up if AmCharts fetches the data correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Try to Parse your JSON data,something like,

```
 chart.dataProvider = JSON.parse(j);
```

This might be work for you.